# How to match only one string and not another

Tags: regex, powergrep

This is String 1:

```
<td class="AAA"><span class="BBB">Text1</span></td>
```

I want to remove the span so it looks like this:

```
<td class="BBB">Text1</td>
```

Which is easy enough with this regex:

```
Search: <td class="AAA"><span class="BBB">(.*)</span></td>
Replace: <td class="BBB">$1</td>
```

The problem: Sometimes the string looks like this (String 2):

```
<td class="AAA"><span class="BBB">Text1</span>-<span class="BBB">Text2</span></td>
```

which also matches because of the 2 closing tags. But I don't want it to be matched at all. How do I find only String 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching any character in your matching group, match all characters aside from the open `<`:

```
Search: <td class="AAA"><span class="BBB">([^<]*)</span></td>
Replace: <td class="BBB">$1</td>
```

This is assuming your `Text1` doesn't contain the `<` character.